Passing temporary object for initializing reference member variable
Consider the below code snippet:
#include <iostream>
class B
{
public:
    B()
    {
        x = 5;
        std::cout << "B's default constructor called, creating object: " << this << "\n";
    }
    B(const B &other)
    {
        std::cout << "B's copy constructor called, copying other object: " << &other << "to this object: " << this << "\n";
    }
    B(B &&other)
    {
        std::cout << "B's Move constructor called, moving other object: " << &other << "to this object: " << this << "\n";
    }

    int x;
};
class A
{
public:
    A(B other_b) : b_(other_b)
    {
        std::cout << "A's constructor called, creating object: " << this << ", Address of b recieved is: " << &other_b << ", Address of A's b: " << &b_ << "\n";
    }
    void print()
    {
        std::cout << "Address of this object: " << this << ", Address of b: " << &b_ << "  " <<b_.x << std::endl;
    }

private:
    B &b_;
};

int main()
{
    A a{B()}; // initializing with temporary
    a.print();
}

Output
g++ -O0 -fno-elide-constructors ref_class_member.cpp  // to disable some comiler optimizations

B's default constructor called, creating object: 0x7ffebd667d5c
A's constructor called, creating object: 0x7ffebd667d50, Address of b recieved is: 0x7ffebd667d5c, Address of A's b: 0x7ffebd667d5c
Address of this object: 0x7ffebd667d50, Address of b: 0x7ffebd667d5c  5

I have following doubts:

When we are calling A's constructor with temporary B object, it should have been cleared as it goes out of scope, So when we call a.print(), we should have received some error when we call b_.x.
What is happening in A's constructor? The constructor which is getting called is  A(B other_b) so here the temporary should have been copied, so why don't we see a copy constructor call?



When we are calling A's constructor with temporary B object, it should have been cleared as it goes out of scope, So when we call a.print(), we should have received some error when we call b_.x.

b_ is a reference to a B object that is local to the constructor. When the constructor exits, that local object is destroyed, leaving b_ as a dangling reference. print() is then invoking undefined behavior trying to do anything with b_ let alone b_.x. There is no guarantee that any kind of error would occur.

What is happening in A's constructor? The constructor which is getting called is A(B other_b) so here the temporary should have been copied, so why don't we see a copy constructor call?

Because there is no copy. You're constructing the A object with a temporary B object, and B has a move constructor, so the temporary is moved into the other parameter. And actually, since C++17, the temporary is required to be optimized away, thus other is default-constructed instead of move-constructed.  In this case, the compiler is ignoring the -fno-elide-constructors option.

Somehow I think (mandatory) copy elission is happening, the output doesn't show the move constructor of B being called only its default constructor

@PepijnKramer you are right. I updated my answer.

g++ -O0 --std=c++11 main.cpp && ./a.out I didn't see B move constructor called.

@cpprust before C++17, the temporary may or may not be optimized away. It depends on the compiler implementation. You are not using -fno-elide-constructors to force the temporary.

Thanks a lot @RemyLebeau, With c++ 11 I am able to see the move constructor call.
